# Windows WinJS App System access

Tags: winjs, uwp

I would like to create my own tool to sort photos and videos from anywhere in the file system, sorting and changing names, and stuff like that (basically a sorting tool with custom sort parameters).

Since windows store apps are easy to distribute I think it could be a nice place to develop it.
while I have nothing against C# or VB that i guess it could be easily done with it, I would like to try the `HTML/CSS/JS` apps of the windows store.
*I'm not looking for profit on this, since is aimed for my family*.

**And I don't really know what kind of access to the file system do these apps have.**

I consider a store app because of the universal model, if necessary I could port it to the phones too, the other option I'm considering is just to use `ironpython` and make it full Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *UWP* apps you don't have the full access to the system files. Of course you get one to the working folder of your app - *LocalFolder*. By using suitable *Capabilities* you can be granted an access to specified libraries like: *Music*, *Photos*, *Videos* and more, known as *KnownFolders*. Additionally you can widely access removable devices. To prevent access violation to work on files in *KnownFolders* you have to use a special broker, which will grant privileges to your app.

The full list of access permitions you [will find at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx).

Comment: You can also ask the user for a specific location using the [`FolderPicker` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I've not checked this so far - can user create folder which is outside capabilities/knownFolders? For example the one which will end with path `c:\MyNewFolder`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, well it seems i'll have to go for my other options